# Azure Linux WebApp - deploy.sh can't install yarn globally

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I am trying to deploy a React app to an Azure linux webapp using kudu deployment. 
I have a pretty standard deploy.sh script with one exception. I want to install the `yarn` package manager via `npm`. 
When attempting `npm install yarn -g` the deployment fails. Looking at the logs it looks like a permissions issue.

`npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /opt/nodejs/6.11.0/lib/node_modules`

Is there a way to install global npm modules on azure linux webapps?

You can see the log here:

```
Command: bash deploy.sh
Installing Yarn
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /opt/nodejs/6.11.0/lib/node_modules
/opt/nodejs/6.11.0/lib
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-1011-azure
`-- yarn@1.6.0 
npm ERR! argv "/opt/nodejs/6.11.0/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "install" "yarn" "-g"

npm ERR! node v6.11.0
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
installing yarn dependency failed
npm ERR! path /opt/nodejs/6.11.0/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/nodejs/6.11.0/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/opt/nodejs/6.11.0/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/opt/nodejs/6.11.0/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Same issue. My only solution so far has been to send my App Service a Docker container with the right files.

Answer (score 0):

You should run your script with sudo if possible. This will overcome the permissions issue

Comment: sudo does not work on the azure webapp environment for some reason. It's not a recognized command.

Comment: What Linux version is it? It’s not default installed on all distros

Comment: The distro is unknown. Azure is using something called Kudu.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the instructions here to use kudu-yarn:
https://github.com/stefangordon/kudu-yarn

It requires you copy a couple files in your project which will get zipped and sent to Azure. When in the App Service, it will utilize the Kudu `.deployment` file and run `deploy.cmd` that they've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to install `serve`. In the end, I had to add `serve` as a dependency in my `package.json` and execute it locally with the startup command set to `node_modules/.bin/serve -s build`. Here is my deployment stage;

```yaml
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
    appType: webAppLinux
    WebAppName: $(webAppName)
    packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    RuntimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
    StartupCommand: 'node_modules/.bin/serve -s build'
    ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
    InlineScript: |
    npm install
```

It is pretty much exactly as Azure DevOps generated it otherwise.